# Return key for a value found in Hashtable

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable

I know how to find a value for a corresponding key in Hashtable but how do I find what key is attached to a specific value? I wrote a function that loops through a String and finds keywords. It does that pretty quickly but I need to return key of that value(keyword) found. This is my method so far

```
public void findKeywords(POITextExtractor te, ArrayList<Hashtable<Integer,String>> listOfHashtables, ArrayList<Integer> KeywordsFound) {
    String document = te.getText().toString();
    String[] words = document.split("\\s+");
    int wordsNo = 0;
    int wordsMatched = 0;
    System.out.println("listOfHashtables = " + listOfHashtables);
    for(String word : words) {
        wordsNo++;
        for(Hashtable<Integer, String> hashtable : listOfHashtables) {
            //System.out.println(hashtable + " found in the document:");
            if(hashtable.containsValue(word)) {

                //<RETURN KEY OF THAT VALUE>

                wordsMatched++;
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of words in document = " + wordsNo);
    System.out.println("Number of words matched: " + wordsMatched);
}
```

Comment: As an aside, is there any reason you're using `Hashtable` rather than `HashMap`? The latter is generally preferred in modern code.

Comment: What Jon Skeet said, plus I feel that perhaps those hashtables should be using the words as keys, rather than the words being the values.

Comment: Some crucial points. Thank you guys. I'm going to change my code in the meantime. On the other hand, are HashMaps more efficient than Hashtables or what's the reason for choosing one over the other?

Comment: Yes, `HashTable` is more efficient, because `Hashtable` and `Vector` and such are only retained for Java's policy of infinite backwards compatibility.

Comment: @dsafasfsafasfsa `are HashMaps more efficient than Hashtables` ?? Exploring this by yourself would be more beneficial to you :)

Answer (score 2):

`containsValue` has to iterate over all the entries in the hash table anyway - so just change your code so that you do that:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : hashtable) {
    if (word.equals(entry.getValue()) {
        // Use entry.getKey() here
    }
}
```

It's not clear to me from the description of the question what your hash tables are intending to represent - but it's at least *unusual* to have a map from integer to string. Are you sure you don't want it the other way round?

Comment: If you run this function for many words it can become quite slow. If each hashtable contains each word once and only once (perfect bijection) then it's more efficient to precalculate a reverse hash table that maps words to ints and use that to query the words.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus: Sure - I suspect if we knew more about what was being requested in general, we'd find all kinds of different approaches. I was answering the question that was specifically asked, given that we don't have more context.